# Работа с цифрами

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Есть числа:

`123456.78901 
-123456.7801`

их нужно разделить как снизу

`"123,456.80"
"-123,456.78"`
**Вопрос**
Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print("{:,.2f}".format(123456.78901))
print("{:,.2f}".format(-123456.7801))
```

> 123,456.79
>
> -123,456.78